# Django getting data from BD

Tags: python, django

Good Afternoon developers:

I have this question for Django Developers, well i did a litte app with my own login, when i used a correct user i get this error `<Usuario: Usuario object> is not JSON serializable` and i'm not using json.       i will show you my code:

### models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from db.managers import TipoUsuarioManager, UsuarioManager, MenuManager, MenuTipoUsuarioManager

#-------------------------------------------------------------------#

#----------Modelo Tipo Usuario-------#

class TipoUsuario(models.Model):

    def validate_vacio_nulo(valor):
        if(valor == '') or (valor == None) or (len(valor) < 3):
            raise ValidationError(u'%s no se puede' % valor)

    nombre   = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators = [validate_vacio_nulo])
    created  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # Usar datetiem.data.today() = import datetime
    updated  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects= TipoUsuarioManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.nombre)

 #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#}

 #-----------------Modelo Usuario ------------------#

class Usuario(models.Model):
    tipousuario = models.ForeignKey(TipoUsuario)
    nombre      = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    login       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    clave       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email       = models.EmailField()
    created     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = UsuarioManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.login, self.nombre)


    class Meta:
        ordering= ['tipousuario', 'nombre']

 #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

 #------------------- Modelo Menu ------------------------#

class Menu(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url    = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    icono  = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    padre  = models.IntegerField()
    orden  = models.IntegerField()
    created= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tipousuario = models.ManyToManyField(TipoUsuario, blank=True, null=True)

    objects= MenuManager() #Para usar managers

def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.nombre)

class Meta:
      ordering= ['padre','orden']




class MenuTipoUsuario(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu)
    tipousuario = models.ForeignKey(TipoUsuario)

    objects= MenuTipoUsuarioManager() #Para Usar Managers

    class Meta:
        #db_table= u'db_menu_tipousuarios'
        ordering= ['tipousuario','menu']
```

### managers.py:

```
from django.db import models

class TipoUsuarioManager(models.Manager):

    def todos(self):
        return self.model.objects.all()

class UsuarioManager(models.Manager):

    def todos(self):
        return self.model.objects.all()

    def login_ok(self, usuario, clave):
        try:
            existe= self.model.objects.get(login= usuario, clave= clave)

        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            return existe


    def cambio_clave(self, id, actual, nueva):
        usuario= self.model.objects.get(id= id)
        if usuario.clave != actual: return False
        usuario.clave= nueva
        usuario.saved()
        return True




#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

class MenuManager(models.Manager):

    def todos(self):
        return self.model.objetcs.all()

class MenuTipoUsuarioManager(models.Manager):

    def todos(self):
        return self.model.objetcs.all()
```

### forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from db.models import TipoUsuario, Usuario, Menu, MenuTipoUsuario

class IngresoForm(forms.Form):
    usuario= forms.CharField(error_messages={'required':'Espacio Requerido!'})
    clave= forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
           error_messages={'required':'Espacio Requerido!'})
```

### views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from db.forms import IngresoForm, CambioPwdForm
from db.models import Usuario

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('home/index.html', locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def acerca_de(request):
    return render_to_response('home/acerca_de.html', locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def ingreso(request):
# formulario - msg_no - ver_error - lista_err: se deben llamar asi, el include las referencia con ese nombre
    valido= False
    ver_error= False
    msg_no='Ingreso no valido'
    lista_err= []

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formulario= IngresoForm(request.POST)
        valido= formulario.is_valid()
        if valido:
            usuario= formulario.cleaned_data['usuario']
            clave=  formulario.cleaned_data['clave']
            usrLog= Usuario.objects.login_ok(usuario,clave)
            if usrLog != None:
                request.session['usuario']= usrLog
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
            else:
                ver_error= True

        else:
            ver_error= True
            for field in formulario:
                for error in field.errors:
                    lista_err.append(field.label + ': '+error)

    else:
        formulario= IngresoForm()

    return render_to_response('home/ingreso.html', locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def cambio_clave(request):
    return render_to_response('home/cambio_clave.html', locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def salir(request):
    #del request.session['usuario']
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
```

### Traceback:

```
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                response = middleware_method(request, response) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py in process_response
                    request.session.save() ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py in save
            session_data=self.encode(self._get_session(no_load=must_create)), ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py in encode
        serialized = self.serializer().dumps(session_dict) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py in dumps
        return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1') ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py in dumps
        **kw).encode(obj) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python34\lib\json\encoder.py in encode
        chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python34\lib\json\encoder.py in iterencode
        return _iterencode(o, 0) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python34\lib\json\encoder.py in default
        raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable") ...
▶ Local vars
```

I'm using django 1.8 and python 3.4. ty if you can help me, yes i'm using sessions and here you are my traceback thank you for anwser.

Comment: Do you use sessions? Data is jsonified for sessions.

Comment: You should post the full traceback, which will give us (and you) some clues about where to look.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your problem is here:

```
request.session['usuario']= usrLog
```

When you do this, you are putting a `Usuario` object into the session, and then the session backend tries to serialize it to put it into a database table. However, as the documentation says:

> Note that unlike `PickleSerializer`, the `JSONSerializer` cannot handle arbitrary Python data types.

(See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#write-your-own-serializer) for the source. The whole page is actually a good read.) `JSONSerializer` is the default for 1.6 and up. I do not recommend switching to `PickleSerializer` for the security issues it entails.

What you could do instead of setting `request.session['usuario']` to a whole `Usuario` object is store the primary key there and the retrieve the corresponding `Usuario` object when you need it. So:

```
request.session['usuario']= usrLog.pk
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, that you said help me to find the problem, this was request.session['usuario']= usrLog needed to put the attribute of the object request.session['usuario']= usrLog.login, if y want to add other attributes i need to put request.session['nombre']= usrLog.nombre and after call this sessions parms in the view. Thank you so much again.